# How to type unicode letters?

Tags: discussion

I am looking for a way to type letters with dot only using keyboard (without any applications). For example, an US keyboard with international layout has letters like this `ç`, but doesn't has like this `ẉ`. How to type such letters?

Comment: Is this for a specific golfing language? Where do you want to type those letters? Only in the browser, or in every application? If in every application, which OS are you on?

Comment: @Adám I am learning Jelly and writing code on TIO (Mozilla & Windows)

Comment: Check if your operating system has a compose key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This in-browser language bar](https://abrudz.github.io/lb/jelly) allows you to type `ẉ` as <kbd>.</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>Tab⭾</kbd> or <kbd>w</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>Tab⭾</kbd>.